# DependencyProperty in UserControl with MVVM Light

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

How to make bind UserControl DepenpencyProperty with MainViewModel property.

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  public MainModel Model{get;set;}
  public MainViewModel()
  {
     Model = new MainModel();
  }
}
```

**MainModel.cs**

```
public class MainModel:ObservableObject
{
  private string text;
  public string Text
  {
    get{return text;}
    set{text=value;RaisePropertyChanged(()=>Text)}
}
```

**MainView.xaml**

```
<Window
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource MainLocator}}">
<someusercontrol:controlEx DP={Binding Model.Text} />
</Window>
```

**ControlEx.xaml**

```
<UserControl  DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator},Path=NewMain}" x:Class="someusercontrol.controlEx ">
</UserControl>
```

**ControlEx.xaml.cs**

```
 public partial class ControlEx:UserControl
 {
  public string DP
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(DPProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(DPProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DPProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "DP",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(ControlEx),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnDPPropertyChanged)));
    private static void OnDPPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ControlEx source = d as ControlEx ;
        (source.DataContext as MainViewModel).Model.UserText= (string)e.NewValue;
       //// some actions
    }
}
```

This sample doesn't work for me, method SetValue in ControlEx doesn't raise. If I changed DP={Binding Model.Text} to DP={"123"}, everything works fine.

**Resolved**

Changing binding to

```
<Window
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource MainLocator}}">
 <someusercontrol:controlEx DP={Binding Main.Model.Text, Source={StaticResource MainLocator}} />
</Window>
```

and it works.

Comment: Do you initialize the `MainViewModel.Model` property anywhere? Note also that you are mixing types `int` and `string` in the declarations or your dependency property.

Comment: Can try setting your Mode to TwoWay in xaml please?  So your xaml will look like DP={Binding Model.Text,Mode=TwoWay}

Comment: you want typeof(int) but then you are using the property as string... are you sure ain't getting any output errors? check them please

Comment: What do you mean "method SetValue in ControlEx doesn't raise". Your setter will not be called in a binding scenario, but OnDPPropertyChanged() should still fire.

Comment: Please don't embed answers in your question. Post them below as an _answer_.  Later if nothing else comes along that is better, you can _accept_ your own answer as the best answer.  Also, don't put **resolved** in titles please